# how to scroll a bottom div to its normal position after reloading page?

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I have two div .
one is header div and another is main div which is displaying content,large content
Consider a senario , if scroll to bottom in webpage again when i relaod/refresh
webpage.i alwalys remain in bottom.

```
$(document).reload(function(){
$("#main").scrollTop(0);
});
```

But this doesnt work.

"#main" div positioned relative and top:100;

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the scrollTop of you `body` element to `0` when the page is loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
});
```

Comment: Now it probably will.

Comment: Its chrome issue.Working fine on firefox

Answer (score 0):

It will work..  html,body is a global selector of screen scroll. so it will control scroll of page. and scrolltop(0) means scroll position will be 0.

```
$(document).reload(function(){
    $("body,html").scrollTop(0);
    });
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer please.